# Wi-fi disconnecting every 5-10 minutes ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, multiple-monitors, dell

I am noticing a weird behaviour on my Dell XPS 13.

I always have blue-tooth headphones connected when I am working. When I have my laptop plugged into an external monitor and having the laptop screen turned off everything seems to be working fine, but if I try to use only the laptop, my wi-fi will start disconnecting every 5-10 minutes and it will take approx. 30 seconds to reconnect.

I have no idea if there is a correlation between the fact that I have a monitor in use or something, but the wi-fi keeps disconnecting if I am just using the laptop.

Any suggestions would be appreciate.

Comment: If the WiFi is using the 2.4GHz band, there’s a good probability that the Bluetooth is interfering and triggering that disconnect. If you’re able to use the 5GHz bands for WiFi, try to stick to those so the more-crowded 2.4GHz band can be used for the Bluetooth (and a bunch of other household devices) 

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.